How do I activate hotreload for NestJs using vagrant?
I'm having a hard time trying to make hotreload work for NestJs in a Vagrant VM. Followed all the instructions on
https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/hot-reload
And here:
Nest.js framework hot reload doesn't work
It just won't hotreload. Any adittional steps for a Vagrant installed NestJs ?
